# mysql query Join table doesn't work

Tags: mysql

here is my query that makes an error for Join

```
        $query = 'SELECT 
                    a.ks_u_id, 
                    a.ks_keyword,
                    b.u_photo 
                FROM 
                '.T_KEYWORD_HISTORY.' a 
                WHERE a.ks_u_id in ( SELECT uf_target_id FROM '.T_USER_FOLLOW.' WHERE uf_user_id="'.$u_id.'" and uf_target_id <> "'.$u_id.'" )
                JOIN '.T_USER_ACCOUNT.' b ON b.u_id = a.ks_u_id 
                ORDER BY a.ks_time DESC 
                LIMIT 0 , 5 ';
```

I get this error message.

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'JOIN T_USER_ACCOUNT b ON b.u_id = a.ks_u_id ORDER BY a.ks_time DESC '` at line 8

```
SELECT 
     a.ks_u_id, a.ks_keyword, b.u_photo 
FROM T_KEYWORD_HISTORY a 
WHERE a.ks_u_id in ( SELECT uf_target_id 
                     FROM T_USER_FOLLOW 
                     WHERE uf_user_id="jake" and uf_target_id <> "jake" ) 
JOIN T_USER_ACCOUNT b ON b.u_id = a.ks_u_id 
ORDER BY a.ks_time DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 5
```

It looks like I wrote wrong query for JOIN command.

Comment: WHERE clause must be after JOIN clauses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT 
     a.ks_u_id, a.ks_keyword, b.u_photo 
FROM T_KEYWORD_HISTORY a 
JOIN T_USER_ACCOUNT b ON b.u_id = a.ks_u_id 
WHERE a.ks_u_id in ( SELECT uf_target_id 
                     FROM T_USER_FOLLOW 
                     WHERE uf_user_id="jake" and uf_target_id <> "jake" ) 
ORDER BY a.ks_time DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The `JOIN` clause comes before the `WHERE` clause.  Your query should be:

```
SELECT 
 a.ks_u_id, a.ks_keyword, b.u_photo 
FROM T_KEYWORD_HISTORY a 
JOIN T_USER_ACCOUNT b ON b.u_id = a.ks_u_id 
WHERE a.ks_u_id in ( SELECT uf_target_id 
                 FROM T_USER_FOLLOW 
                 WHERE uf_user_id="jake" and uf_target_id <> "jake" ) 
ORDER BY a.ks_time DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 5
```